# What is the performance analyzer in vs2012 doing differently?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I decided to try out the performance analyzer thingy in vs 2012. To my surprise, the test code(way too big to post) runs about 15% faster when analyzing than in the default release configuration over the length of ~1 minute. What could be the reason for this? Is it using different compiler flags or something?

To elaborate a bit more on the code: Its a specialized spatial sorting algorithm(most similar to counting sort) that operates on relatively simple pod classes and is looped 10k times, IO times are excluded from being timed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I think I finally got a clue. When I run the program from the IDE, I think the thingy that allows for breakpoints in code is slowing it down, can't break in the analyzer. To confirm I ran the program from the .exe instead and surely enough it was even faster than it was in the analyzer (not by much but still), probably because it didn't have the sampler poking at it. Mystery solved!